# c# Opening up a form depending on the linklabel name

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combobox that dictates the linklabel name, I would like to select the linklabel depending on the name of it. Here is what I have done so far. First part of the if statement works but the second does not.

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
   if((string)linkLabel1.Text == "Advanced Software Engineering") 
   {
      Form4 g = new Form4();
      g.Show();
   }  
   else if((string)linkLabel1.Text == "Web Research")
   {
      Form5 g1 = new Form5();
      g1.Show();
   }
}
```

Comment: I assume you have linkLabel1_LinkClicked linked to more than one linklabel? If you do, to get linklabel the user clicked on can be obtained by casting sender to LinkLabel and then using Text property of the cast result.

Comment: ...and what is the problem?

Comment: The second if statement does not work on the same linklabel

Comment: It will not help the problem, but do you really need a cast to `string` there?

Comment: Also, are you sure you use your combobox correctly (i.e. maybe you should've connected to its event or read the text from combobox instead of linklabels)? There is nothing about it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? Your approach would work fine.

However I would create my own FormBase that has a property called "LinkLabel"
Each WinForm would then set the LinkLable its designed to be used by.

Then in your LinkClicked event do something like this

```
foreach(FormBase _base in _Forms)
{
     if(_base.LinkLabel == linkLabel1.Text)
     {
        _base.Show();
        break;
     }
}
```

EDIT: This wouldn't work if the event is not called by clicking on linkLable1

Comment: How would i go about creating my own FormBase as this is new to me

Comment: Create a new class called FormBase and then make in inherent Form. Then in your forms change the inheritance from Form to FormBase